# Converting ASCII code to a character value

Tags: c, character, ascii

I've just started learning how to program in C and I'm trying to make a program that accepts a number and uses it as an ASCII value to return the ASCII character associated with that value.

The program works when the parameters are predefined but when I introduce the scanf function it compiles but doesnt give me the same results.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    question2();
    return 0; 
}

int question2(void)
{


    int myInt = 65;

    scanf("%d", myInt);
    char ch = myInt;

    printf("%c",ch);

    return 0;
}
```

Cheers and thanks for any help guys.

Comment: Please turn on your compiler's warnings, and read them carefully.

Comment: Also, turn on debugging information. On Linux you should compile with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -g yourcode.c -o yourprog` and use `gdb ./yourprog` to debug it.

Comment: @Mat I don't see a warning when using Dev-C++ which uses TDM-GCC 4.6.1 64-bit though I was expecting it to. Interesting.

Comment: @AlvinWong: That's really strange. GCC (4.5 and up) prints a warning for the scanf even if you don't enable any warnings explicitly. You'll get a warning for the implicit declaration of question2 with Wall

Comment: @Mat Oh well I just tried `scanf` with a variable that isn't a pointer (that of course didn't throw any warning), and I missed the point of implicit declaration in the OP. BTW doesn't "implicit declaration" even *fails* to compile??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the *address* of `myInt` to `scanf()` (the compiler should have emitted a warning for this):

```
scanf("%d", &myInt);
```

You should also check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure `myInt` was actually assigned to. `scanf()` returns the number of assignments made, which in this case is expected to be `1`:

```
if (1 == scanf("%d", &myInt))
{
}
```

Note that `int` has a larger range values than a `char` so you should check that the value stored in `myInt` will *fit* into a `char`. There are macros defined in the header `limits.h` that you can use to check:

```
if (1 == scanf("%d", &myInt))
{
    if (myInt >= CHAR_MIN && myInt <= CHAR_MAX)
    {
        printf("%c\n", (char) myInt);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d out-of-range: min=%d, max=%d\n",
            myInt, CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
    }
}
```

The compiler should have also emitted an *implicit function declaration* warning with respect to `question2()`. To correct, place the definition of `question2()`, or a declaration for `question2()`, prior to `main()`.

Comment: Ye that worked thanks for that ! I think I was trying to pass the variable itself rather than the address as you explained. Cheer mate