# Integers to strings

Tags: c, string, integer

I want to convert some integers to be letters in C; I need a function that helps me to do that... for instance, if I write 101, the function will help me convert this into 'e'. 
Can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [help] and [ask] sections on how to ask a proper question.  This is not a proper question.

Comment: These lecturers are getting imaginative with the homework. You gotta hand it to them

Comment: What do you know about `scanf()`?  What about `atoi()` or `strtol()`?  What do you know about characters and integers?  Do you know what the type of the constant `'e'` is?

Comment: None of scanf, atoi, or strtol are relevant here.

Comment: clarification: They might be relevant if the integers are in the input stream, but the question doesn't mention that.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at this thread: [Converting ASCII code to a character value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953665/converting-ascii-code-to-a-character-value)

Basically, you just can do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()

    int val = 101;
    char ret = 0;

    if (val >= CHAR_MIN && val <= CHAR_MAX)
    {
        ret = val;
        printf("%c\n", ret);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Though +1 for correctness, this site is not intended for make homework for others.

Comment: @Valeri I assume you meant "do homework". Can you point to a) where the OP says this is homework or b) where the site says that homework questions are not to receive answers?

Comment: @JimBalter you are right. My bad. I have nothing against giving answers to homework questions, as long as it is visible that the person, who asks, have done some work already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am looking for the function that helps me to accoplish my work! This funtion is not my homework!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void i2s(char *str, const int *ints){
    while(*str++ = *ints++);
}

int main(){
    int integers[] = {104,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100,0};
    char strings[sizeof(integers)/sizeof(*integers)];
    i2s(strings, integers);
    printf("%s\n", strings);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for eveyone of you guys, I am still learning and I believe I didn't address my question precisly. What I actually wanted is that:

char a;
a=79;

and that's should print as a charecter in the printf,
thanks for help.